# Could not autowire. No beans of 'CustomUserDetailsService' type found. in spring security configuration

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security, and like any other service, I created the customUserDetailsService interface and wrote a CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl to implement it. However, I encountered the same error as the title in the SecurityConfig.

Using the same example, I also wrote a service called JwtService, which has the same structure, but the error does not occur in that service.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class SecurityConfig(
    private val customUserDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
    private val jwtService: JwtService
) {
...
}


interface CustomUserDetailsService: UserDetailsService {
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String?): CustomUserDetails
}

@Service
class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl(val accountService:AccountService): UserDetailsService {
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String?): CustomUserDetails {
        try {
            val account = accountService.findByEmail(username!!)
            return CustomUserDetails(account)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

I found that replacing the structure with the following doesn't cause an error.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class SecurityConfig(
    private val customUserDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
    private val jwtService: JwtService
) {
...
}

@Service
class CustomUserDetailsService(val accountService:AccountService): UserDetailsService {
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String?): CustomUserDetails {
        try {
            val account = accountService.findByEmail(username!!)
            return CustomUserDetails(account)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error...

Comment: you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended, and if you are to use jwts you should read the jwt chapter of spring seccurity and use the built in features so that the usage is correct and secure.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I didn't know, why can't I handle JWT with the browser? I'm configuring a spring boot server with rest api, and I'm implementing login by passing accessToken and refreshToken tokens to the browser when logged in.

Comment: You should not hand out tokens to browsers, read the oauth2 spec and/or the OIDC spec, tokens are handed out in cookies and jwts are used within private networks between service to service calls.